# Testing digital certificates

Tags: testing, digital-certificate

I wonder if anyone knows a way to carry out tests with digital certificates.

My application works with digital certificates smoothly. However, when the configured digital certificate expires or is not properly installed on the machine, the application displays some errors. I need digital certificates for testing. Invalid, expired, valid ... Is that possible or I am wondering too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate expired certificates yourself. It's more complex task to get certificates which are revoked and whose status is reported via server-side CRL or OCSP responder. I believe you would need to create an infrastructure (such as a test OCSP responder and test CRLs) to do such tests.